# Horizontal scrolling: wrap all elements horizontally without fixed width and with no gaps

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

I created a horizontal scrolling page with a lot of images positioned next to each other. The images have to be positioned inline to align them vertically centered. Also they must not exceed and have to adapt to the viewport. To achieve the responsive effect I wrote a little JS-script that forces the browser to repaint the inline elements, which normally would only happen after reload.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qACEX/4/).

My problem is: I want the `.container` to horizontally wrap all containing elements with no gaps between the images. Unfortunately almost every browser behaves different. To make it more visual I colored the `.container` in grey and gave the wrapping `ul` a green border.

In Firefox, Opera and modern IE all images are wrapped perfectly if I add `float: left;` to the `.container`. However this has no effect in Chrome and Safari: The wrapping ends with the width of the viewport.

Do you have a solution how to achieve the same effect in Webkit browsers?

Additionally, if I decrease the height of the viewport, gaps appear next to some of the images (but not in Safari ...). Those gaps look like a padding within the list elements, all different in size. If I remove the horizontal scrollbar with `overflow: hidden;` the gaps disappear in Chrome, but not in Firefox. In IE the gaps are even wider.

In HTML I already removed all white-space characters.

What's the cause of those gaps and how can I remove them in every browser?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you should use white-space and not float on .container too, since it is the main wrapper

Comment: test this : http://jsfiddle.net/qACEX/5/

Comment: In my opinion the `ul.list` needs the nowrap property since it is the wrapper for the inline elements. But I'm not quite sure. However this didn't work. Furthermore: without the `float:left;` the `.container` doesn't even wrap the content in Firefox and IE.  I just found out that a Repaint on the images or a reload removes the gaps at least in Chrome. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qACEX/6/)

Comment: I agree , you could try using display:flex or table / table-cell .  A hudge right margin to .container may as well reduce virtually its size to almost nothing and would let chrome safari to extend beyond viewport . Actually, in W7 chrome/safari , i do not experiment the bug you described in your updated fiddle.